# How to use external object in Vue's data() function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

So, the stadard way of defining data in Vue component is by using the data function like in the following example:

```
data()
{
    return {
        a:0
    }
}
```

My question is, instead of defining the data object after `return`, can I define the data object somewhere else and just create its instance in `data` function?

So, for example:

Inside Vue component:

```
data()
{
    return new DataObject();
}
```

and then in DataObject.js do:

```
class DataObject
{
    constructor(a)
    {
        this._a = a;
    }
    get a()
    {
        return this._a;
    }
    set a(a)
    {
        if (a > 0)
        {
            this._a = a;
        }
        else
        {
            this._a = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work.
I created the following workaround which enables me to do this:

```
data()
{
    return {
        data: new DataObject();
    }
}
```

and this works as expected, but I still define the wrapper data object in order to be able to use data object and I have to access the `a` as `this.data.a` instead of just `this.a`.

So, is it possible to implement this on my way, without defining the data nor wrapper data object inside the `data` function?

So I want to be able to return external data object from the `data` function.

Comment: It seems you want to use a store..? [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) can help you organize your data throughout your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to construct the object outside of the data prop. The problem with the OP code is the `DataObject`'s getters. vue will replace those with reactive get/set, deleting the knowledge of the underlying variable.

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 'A';
    this.b = 'B';
    this.c = 'C';
  }
  // get a() will be overwritten
}

window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
      return new SomeClass()
    },
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>{{a}}</h3>
  <h3>{{b}}</h3>
  <h3>{{c}}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly! Getters were getting overwritten and that is why I was not able to access data when returned by using ```return new DataObject();``` Once I removed getters it now works as expected. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you are not providing a name to the object you are trying to create

```
return new DataObject();
```

try instantiating the class somewhere in your code first and then return it

```
let instance = new DataObject();
```

```
return instance;
```

Comment: I tried, but it does not work. So ```<script> import DataObject from "./DataObject"; let dataObject = new DataObject(); export default { data() { return dataObject; } }</script>``` does not work either. This is Vue component, in plain JavaScript it would work, but in Vue components it does not.